# Xcode set default button on enter when making a form

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, button

I'm making a form in Xcode using objective-c and cocoa. In the interface builder I have 2 textfields and 2 buttons. When I build the project and run it, neither of the two buttons are selected (highlighted in blue as opposed to white). When the user is writing in the text field the ENTER key needs to trigger one of the buttons to be pressed.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You set the Key Equivalent value for your button in IB. Just click on that field in the  attributes inspector and press the enter key.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! That was exactly what I needed. I'm not sure how I managed to miss it when it was right in front of me...

Answer (score 4):

A link to Apple's documentation is here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Button/Articles/MakingaButtontheDefaultButton.html

this code sets the return key to be the default:

```
[myButton setKeyEquivalent:@"\r"];
```

not mentioned in the docs, but to programmatically remove that key, you would use:

```
[myButton setKeyEquivalent:@""];
```

Comment: Don't forget to use the **Push** button style as well or you won't see the blue button!